# How to specify Git remote's URL for Maven Release plugin using standard SSH syntax?

Tags: java, git, maven, ssh

### Straight to specific problem

If I specify "fully qualified" SSH address with path in `pom.xml`

```
<scm>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:username@hostname:/absolute/path/to/repo.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

and use it in command like

```
mvn --batch-mode release:prepare -Dtag=whatever -DreleaseVersion=3.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=4.0-SNAPSHOT
```

then I get error like

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project maven_dependencies: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: 'hostname/absolute/path/to/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**NOTE:** The semicolon between `hostname` and `/absolute/path/to/repo.git` which was in `pom.xml` disappeared in the error output!

### Additional details

**Absolute vs relative path**

Actually, I'm able to use Git with *non-absolute* path in SSH URL (relative to `usernname`'s home directory). For example, using

```
scm:git:username@hostname:path/to/repo.git
```

instead of

```
scm:git:username@hostname:/home/username/path/to/repo.git
```

works perfectly.

**Official documentation**

I've read [official Maven Release documentation](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) for Git and, because standard SSH-like URL already worked at least in relative path case, I deliberately ignore its weird URL specification:

```
scm:git:ssh://username@hostname[:port]/~/path/to/repository
```

The reason to rebel and ignore this syntax is inability to imply path relative to user's home (which SSH does by default if path does not start with `/`). Moreover, colon `:` after `hostname` for standard SSH-like URL is a delimiter between `hostname` and path (*not* a port number)!

This means that Git URLs for SSH have to be specifically re-formatted for Maven Release plugin - what a headache!

Comment: Going forward, I had to comply with the spec in the documentation and confuse everyone who is going to look at such URLs. So, it already works. The question is more about alternative to use standard SSH-like URLs.